# Why does GEKKO return a decimal value for an integer variable in my optimization code?

Tags: gekko

Why does GEKKO optimisation return a decimal value for an Integer variable?

Hello everyone,
With my GEKKO code I want to optimise a cutting pattern, with the maximum surface area of rectangles in the area of a circle.

All my variables are predefined and are integer:

- `diam`: 1 diameter from the list
- `ep` and `larg`: 1 thickness and 1 width linked together by dictionary
- `pcs`: number of rectangles pieces, between 1 and 14 and also integer.

I could optimise my problem without Gekko, by testing all the possibilities with nested loops, but I want to add new variables afterwards, which would lead to too many possibilities for the loops.

I therefore use GEKKO with the principle of binary decision variables for almost all my variables.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO 
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#define diameter of circle
diam = [205,225,237,255,269,286,295,305]
xdiam = [m.Var(lb=0, ub=1, integer=True) for _ in diam]
m.Equation(sum(xdiam) == 1)

#define numbers of pieces
pcs = m.Var(lb=1, ub=14, integer=True, value=10)
#define thickness et width
dic = {
    12:[75,95,100],
    15:[95,100,150],
    10:[100,135,120]}
pair = []
for cle in dic:
    for val in dic[cle]:
        xpair = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1, integer=True)
        pair.append((cle,val, xpair))
m.Equation(sum(xl[2] for xl in pair) == 1)

#constraint : diagonal of all rectangles (hypotenuse) 
#  must not exceed the diameter
pyth = m.Intermediate((((sum((e*xe) for e,_,xe in pair))*pcs \
  +((pcs-1)*3.5))**2+(sum((l*xl) for _,l,xl in pair))**2)**0.5)
m.Equation(pyth <= sum((d*xd) for d, xd in zip(diam, xdiam)))

#Maximise area of rectangles/area of circle
rend = m.Intermediate(((sum((l*xl) for _,l,xl in pair))*(sum((e*xe) \
  for e,_,xe in pair))*pcs)/((((sum((d*xd) \
  for d, xd in zip(diam, xdiam)))*0.5)**2)*3.14))
m.Maximize(rend)

#Solver
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000 
m.solve()

#Display results
for ep,larg,bin in pair:
    if float(bin.value[0]) > 0.90:
        print("thi",ep)
        print("wid",larg)
for diam, xdiam in zip(diam,xdiam):
    if xdiam.VALUE[0] > 0.9:
        print("diam",diam)
print("pcs",pcs.VALUE[0])
print("yield",rend.VALUE[0])
print("pyth",pyth.VALUE[0])
```

And I don't know why the optimal solution proposed for the number of pieces is not an integer value?

In this example the `pcs` result is pretty close to an integer value, but by modifying the sections in the dictionary I can come up with values like : `pcs = 5.820173`.

```
 The solution was found.
 The final value of the objective function is  -0.5289469114205082
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  0.0211 sec
 Objective      :  -0.5289469114205082
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
thi 15
wid 150
diam 205
pcs 7.9775445419
yield 0.52894691142
pyth 205.00005502
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solver needs to be selected. It is currently IPOPT with `m.options.SOLVER = 3` as a Nonlinear Programming (NLP) solver that does not attempt to find an integer solution. However, the IPOPT solver is very good at finding an initial guess for the APOPT solver as a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) solver. By default, the `minlp_integer_tol` (integer tolerance) is 0.01. This means that `0.99` and `1.01` are both considered integer solutions. This tolerance can be adjusted to a more stringent requirement such as `1e-6`. Try this sequence of solutions to find a more exact integer solution:

```py
# Initialize with IPOPT (NLP Solver)
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()

# Find Integer solution with APOPT (MINLP Solver)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-4',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1.0e-6',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500']
m.solve()
```

The solution is:

```
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   3.590000000258442E-002 sec
 Objective      :  -0.510288956224352     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
thi 15
wid 150
diam 237
pcs 10.0
yield 0.51028895622
pyth 235.46178034
```

Here is the complete script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO 
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

#define diameter of circle
diam = [205,225,237,255,269,286,295,305]
xdiam = [m.Var(lb=0, ub=1, integer=True) for _ in diam]
m.Equation(sum(xdiam) == 1)

#define numbers of pieces
pcs = m.Var(lb=1, ub=14, integer=True, value=10)
#define thickness et width
dic = {
    12:[75,95,100],
    15:[95,100,150],
    10:[100,135,120]}
pair = []
for cle in dic:
    for val in dic[cle]:
        xpair = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1, integer=True)
        pair.append((cle,val, xpair))
m.Equation(sum(xl[2] for xl in pair) == 1)

#constraint : diagonal of all rectangles (hypotenuse) 
#  must not exceed the diameter
pyth = m.Intermediate((((sum((e*xe) for e,_,xe in pair))*pcs \
  +((pcs-1)*3.5))**2+(sum((l*xl) for _,l,xl in pair))**2)**0.5)
m.Equation(pyth <= sum((d*xd) for d, xd in zip(diam, xdiam)))


#Maximise area of rectangles/area of circle
rend = m.Intermediate(((sum((l*xl) for _,l,xl in pair))*(sum((e*xe) \
  for e,_,xe in pair))*pcs)/((((sum((d*xd) \
  for d, xd in zip(diam, xdiam)))*0.5)**2)*3.14))
m.Maximize(rend)

m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000 

# Initialize with IPOPT (NLP Solver)
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()

# Find Integer solution with APOPT (MINLP Solver)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-4',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1.0e-6',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500']
m.solve()

#Display results
for ep,larg,bin in pair:
    if float(bin.value[0]) > 0.90:
        print("thi",ep)
        print("wid",larg)
for diam, xdiam in zip(diam,xdiam):
    if xdiam.VALUE[0] > 0.9:
        print("diam",diam)
print("pcs",pcs.VALUE[0])
print("yield",rend.VALUE[0])
print("pyth",pyth.VALUE[0])
```

Comment: Hello John, thank you very much, it works well by specifying these parameters